# How do I remove duplicate words in a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I've been trying to remove duplicate words from a string, and it's not working.

I have the current string:

```
const categories = 'mexican, restaurant, mexican, food, restaurant'
```

and I want this outcome:

```
const x = 'mexican restaurant food'
```

I have tried the following:

```
const x = categories.replace(/,/g, '');

    const uniqueList = x
      .split()
      .filter((currentItem, i, allItems) => {
        return i === allItems.indexOf(currentItem);
      })
      .join();
```

Which is giving me:

```
uniqueList = 'chinese restaurant chinese food restaurant'
```

What is wrong with the code above?

Comment: Convert the string to an array and throw it into a `Set`. This will automatically give you a unique list that you can convert back to a string.

Comment: calling `split` with no argument just gives you back a singleton array holding the entire string. You should split on the space character.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in one single line. Try this code below:

```
const categories = 'mexican, restaurant, mexican, food, restaurant';
let result = [...new Set(categories.split(", "))].join(" ");
```

> Output: "mexican restaurant food"

The output will be exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I like using [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for this kind of purposes. Read in the documentation:

> The Set object lets you store unique values of any type, whether primitive values or object references.

This can work for you:

```js
const categories = 'mexican, restaurant, mexican, food, restaurant'.split(', ');

const unique = Array.from(new Set(categories));

console.log(unique);

console.log(unique.join(' '));
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

In `String.prototype.split(separator)` method, which is used by you, if separator is missed will be returned array with one element - source string. So in your code should be `.split(' ')` instead of `.split()`.
But better use `.split(', ')` without `const x = categories.replace(/,/g, '');`. And even you can `.split(/\s*,\s*/)`, in this way you don't have to care about spaces.
Join by default use ',' as separator. So you should write `.join(' ')`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const categories = 'mexican, restaurant, mexican, food, restaurant';

    const uniqueList = categories
      .split(', ') // split the string when a comma + space is found
      .filter((currentItem, i, allItems) => {
        return i === allItems.indexOf(currentItem);
      }) // filter out duplicates
      .join(' '); // rejoin array to string
      
 console.log( uniqueList );
```

Answer (score 0):

**This Could be done By below code**

```js
const categories = 'mexican,restaurant,mexican,food,restaurant'
const x = 'mexican restaurant food'

var a = categories.split(',')
console.log(a)
var b = []
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  if (!b.includes(a[i])) {
    b.push(a[i])
  }
}
var c = b.toString()
console.log(c)
```